# Do not remove in-app purchased content when application update

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

in my application users can load content from my server. Then this content stored in

**EDIT:** <strike>application bundle</strike>, NSLibraryDirectory

so when I release new version and user updates application, all content is lost and users should load it again.
How can I store the content in order not to lose it when update?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the application bundle is read only, so you can't dynamically store downloaded content there even if you want to. If you're asking what I think you're asking, the normal Document directory should work well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>I don't even know how you can write to the application bundle.</strike> (Obsolete after your edit.) You should store the content in the application documents directory. It should stay there and persist through the updates.

Comment: ... Yes, but the folder of choice seems to be the `Library/Caches` and not the `Documents` folder. See more in Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/

Comment: Yes, but your source states explicitly that this is for data that can be **downloaded again or recreated**. As stated, the only data that is going to be persisted across updates has to be in the `Documents` folder. To prevent synching with iCloud, you can always create a folder with a `.nosync` extension.

Comment: As far as I know, the `Documents` folder's content is not "the only data that is going to be persisted across updates", the `Library/Caches` also does. Or do I miss some docs. Apple only says that the  `Library/Caches` folder is not backed up by iTunes and may deleted "on rare occasions" and "removes files in this directory during a full restoration of the device"( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4 ).

Comment: Moreover one of our apps where rejected by Apple for using the Documents folder for storing downloaded and (by that recoverable) content

Comment: Fact is, you cannot guarantee that the cached folder is not going to be deleted. If you want to prevent that, you have to use the Documents folder. I know about many apps the passed the app store doing that (e.g. The Economist's Intelligent Life Magazine).

Comment: Ours passed as well, until we load up an update after invention of iCloud. Apple changed their policy then.